# C++ Ifstream with multiple columns ( a variable amount of them ) error

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am working on this C++ application that reads in text from a text file that is separated by spaces; each item that is read in represents a property on my class. 
The problem is that the text file does not contain a definite amount of columns, for example:

Ideal Input:

```
Radar Shepard Male 3 Displasia Yes
```

Input variation:

```
Kojak Doberman Male 5 Cough
```

Input variation:

```
Kaiya Tabby 8 Fleas No
```

I am currently reading it in like this:

```
inputFile >> name >> breed >> gender >> age >> problem >> breedSpecificCondition;
```

Which works **great** for the *Ideal Input* scenario, however, whenever a variation occurs, it crashes.
I get why that makes sense, however, I do not know how to best handle it. I am fairly new to C++. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to define what scenarios you want to handle in what way before someone can suggest something.

Comment: You have to clearly specify what the input can look like, and then write code to handle all of the alternatives. Your examples are a start, but it’s not clear just what’s allowed and what isn’t.

Comment: @PeteBecker suppose that those are the only 3 inputs. I am not looking for someone to grind out code and answer this for me, I just am having a hard time figuring out how to determine which scenario i am working with ( ideal, variation1, or variation2 ) when I am reading in the string. Does that make sense?

Comment: If future inputs can be inferred from the present input you can use a state machine. I can't think of a good way to tell whether gender is there or not or other than checking if token 3 is numeric. But what if the animal has a complex name that requires three or more tokens? You may need to establish a more complicated protocol.

Comment: What does the first word in the input mean? What does the second word mean? What does the third word mean? What does the number mean? What does the next word mean? What does the last word mean? Which of those fields is required and which ones are optional? From looking at the input, how do you know which fields are present? Once you clearly understand all that, start writing code. Read a full line of text and look through it, applying the rules about the fields, to figure out what you have. For example, it looks like when the third input field is a number there is no sex.

Comment: This is what `std::getline` is for: reads a single line of text into a `std::string`. Doesn't matter how many words there are on a line. One word. A trillion words. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you. That is what i needed - I was not looking for you guys to program a set of rules to determine what was what when reading it in. I was having a hard time getting ifstream to recognize that there was nothing there. It would either crash when it was a variation, or it would stuff a character from the next line in there. You can't make a ruleset in that situation. std::getline() looks like it will do the job - I am new to c++ and have never used that before.